# Eager loading not working in EF 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am having a method that returns me a list of employees.

```
public Employee GetAdminTypeAndPermission(int userID)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
    {
        var employeeRepo =
            new EmployeeRepository(new EFRepository<Employee>(), unitOfWork);

        DbSet<Employee> employeeObjSet =
            ((EmployeeEntities)employeeRepo.Repository.UnitOfWork.Context).Employees;

        return employeeObjSet.Where(emp => emp.FK_UserID == userID).
            Include("AdminType.Permissions").FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

In another method I am trying to use like,

```
var employee= GetAdminTypeAndPermission(loginInfo.UserID);
var permission = employee.AdminType.Permissions.FirstOrDefault();
```

I am getting an error at the following line:

```
var permission = employee.AdminType.Permissions.FirstOrDefault();
```

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.
>    I understand the Context object disposes after the end of using block but I am using Eager loading to access the Navigation properties and I should get the result set.

Please help me in understanding what mistake I am doing here and how should I correct.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the internals of `employee.AdminType.Permissions`. How is `Permissions` retrieved behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

You have your DbContext in a using statement:

```
using (var unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
```

Once you get out of this using statement, your connection to the database is effectively closed. Either:

- Query the information you need while inside your function (and inside your using statement) or
- Pass in the DbContext to the method so you can continue to use it:

  ```
  using (var unitOfWork = new EFUnitOfWork())
  {
      var employee= GetAdminTypeAndPermission(loginInfo.UserID, unitOfWork); //DbContext passed in
      var permission = employee.AdminType.Permissions.FirstOrDefault();
  }
  ```

Comment: It may actually be employeeRepo in this case (the use looks a little odd to me) but the reason should still be the same.

Comment: He is trying to eager load it. It does not matter if the ctx is disposed. If the related navigation collection/entity is eager loaded it does not get a lazy load reference and does not need a "live" DbContext. But what you've done here should solve the problem because you're explicitly saving the value into a local var. It's OK if it's suitable for him as the proper solution. Agreed on passing the DbContext reference for later use.

Comment: Its the FirstOrDefault that causes the Eager loading, which still needs to be done in the context. Alternative could involve an include to pull it all in a single query but it'd just be more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you got the related table name wrong? What I mean, *stringly typed stuff* is hard to control in your code, i.e. is it maybe (Permission without the last 's'?):

```
return employeeObjSet.Where(emp => emp.FK_UserID == userID).
            Include("AdminType.Permission").FirstOrDefault();
```

For this kind of error I would advise you to use the lambda extension property name resolver, i.e. the overload/extension of the Include method which will be included if you enter the following using directive:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

This is the extension I tend to use:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T, TProperty>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> path);
```

It's used like this:

```
return employeeObjSet.Where(emp => emp.FK_UserID == userID).
        Include(x => x.Permissions).FirstOrDefault();
```

Here its x.Permission**s** because of the ICollection pluralization of the ef generator or your cf coding standard you use.

Hope it helps.